# Функция fprintf в Си

Tags: c, fprintf

Написал программу работы с матрицами и векторами. Все вычисления провел выше, осталось только вывести результаты в файл. Матрица объявлена как double. Вот фрагмент кода:

```
FILE *inputfile;
    inputfile = fopen("input.txt", "w+"); 
fprinf(inputfile, "Матрица С \r\n\r\n"); 

for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <N; j++) {

        fprintf(inputfile,"%.2lf", C[i][j]);
        fprinf(inputfile, "\t\t");
    }

    fprintf(inputfile, "\r\n\r\n");
}


fclose(inputfile);
```

При компиляции выдает ошибки. f:\mingw\include\stdio.h:453:38: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'double'. и другие.

Comment: Во-первых, если компилятор выдает вам ошибки в `mingw\include\stdio.h` (!), то значит, что вы напортачили где-то в другом месте. Во-вторых, что такое `fprinf`? Вы что, код здесь в вопросе *руками* набирали с нуля?

Comment: в-третьих, `note` это не _ошибка_, а _замечание_; ошибка должна быть одну или несколько строк назад. Стоит приводить полный вывод компилятора...

Comment: Вы бы переменную ` C[i][j]` показали как она объявлена, есть предположение что она `char` а не `double`  :)

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте добавить (char *) перед указателем на матрицу, который передается в функцию fprintf.

```
fprintf(inputfile,"%.2lf", (char *) C[i][j]);
```

Comment: Это только усугубит ошибку :)